# VPN issue - Routing and remote Access - Win 2012 R2

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2012, rras

I have VM (Windows server 2012 R2) setup in HyperV and installed Remote and routing access to setup VPN by referring to this [article](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles-tutorials/windows-server-2012/configure-vpn-windows-server-2012-r2.html).

I can connect to this VPN server from another VM without any issue. But, when checking IP address from online tool, it shows same VM's IP address instead of VPN IP. Though I can access internet without any issue, I am seeing “No Internet Access” on network card.

[image]

P.S. Both VMs have public IP address. Nothing is on local IP address.

Checked all posts with no success. Any Suggestion?

Comment: UPDATE:  I have a virtual machine with windows server 2012 R2 OS. This VM has 12 usable public IP addresses.

I have installed DHCP server on this machine and added IP range in Scope of DHCP.

After this, I set "Obtain IP address automatically" in network card to enable DHCP on this network interface. When I run ipconfig /all, I am seeing DHCP enabled on the network interface. But, it assigns random IP address which is neither allocated to the VM nor added in DHCP scope. Due to this VM/VPN is not accessible.

Any idea how do I assign IP from the DHCP scope to machine?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, got this fixed.. Here are the steps if someone faces the same issue.

→ Add two network cards on the machine. Keep one static with public IP addresses. And Add few local IP addresses on second network card. Set naming convention like 'Internal' and 'External' to avoid any confusion at the time of VPN configuration. 
→ Install RRAS role and make sure that you SELECT ROUTING feature while installing RRAS role. 
→ Once the role is installed, you will be asked for post configuration. Right click on server name on RRAS configuration wizard, select 'Configure and enable Routing and remote access'. Follow the steps on installation wizard. 
→ In configuration, select “Virtual Private Network (VPN) access and NAT”.

→ While installation, you will be asked to select network card. Select external network that has public IPs with Internet and proceed.
→ In IPV4 assignment, select static IP address. Set start and end IP address. For example: 192.168.3.151 to 192.168.3.160.

Restart RRAS service once and try to connect from client machine. DO NOT forget to allow access to user (Which will be used for VPN connection) in network access permission.

For those, who is looking for the detailed steps by step guidance, click [here](https://www.accuwebhosting.com/blog/2016/10/06/install-vpn-rras-remote-routing-access/). I found complete solution from this blog.